# Proving the Rietz-Fischer Theorem for $p = \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

**Rietz-Fischer Theorem:** Let $E$ be a measurable set and $1 \le p \le \infty$.  Then every rapidly Cauchy sequence in $L^p(E)$ converges both with respect to the $p$-norm and pointwise almost everyone on $E$ to a function in $L^p(E)$.

**Question:** How does one prove this in the case that $p = \infty$?  Every proof I have seen thus far seems to assume that $p \in [1,\infty)$.  For example, the [wikipedia proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Fischer_theorem#Completeness_of_Lp.2C_.C2.A00.C2.A0.3C_p.C2.A0.E2.89.A4_.E2.88.9E) makes this assumption and then concludes by remarking "the case $p = \infty$ reduces to a simple question about uniform convergence".  Upon thinking about this for a bit it's not obvious how to proceed.

Comment: Refer to this thread: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9321/understanding-proof-of-completeness-of-l-infty