# A question about uniform convergence in proof that $L^\infty$ is Banach.

Tags: measure-theory, banach-spaces, uniform-convergence

I was reading this post [Understanding proof of completeness of $L^{\infty}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9321/understanding-proof-of-completeness-of-l-infty) and it is mentioned that the sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb
N}$ converges uniformly on a conegligible set $N^C$. Could someone point out any useful consequences of this observation?

Comment: It shows that a) a pointwise a.e. limit exists, b) that limit is measurable, and c) that limit is essentially bounded.

Comment: @DanielFischer I see the first two points you listed but in the following way: there is a measurable conegligible set $E$ such that the sequence$(f_n(x))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy for all $x\in E$, so simply define $f=\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)\right)\chi_E$. Not sure if this is correct. What about point c)?

Comment: You want the limit to be in $L^\infty$, so it ought to be essentially bounded. The uniform convergence on a set whose complement has measure $0$ is a quick way to get that. (And you want the sequence to converge to the limit function in the norm, so it's necessary that it converges uniformly on a conegligible set.)

Comment: Are you perhaps using some standard result in the last part of your post?

Comment: Suppose $\lVert f_n - f_m\rVert_\infty \leqslant 1$ for all $n,m \geqslant K$. Then $$\lvert f(x)\rvert = \lim_{n\to\infty} \lvert f_n(x) - f_K(x) + f_K(x)\rvert \leqslant \lvert f_K(x)\rvert + \lim_{n\to\infty} \lvert f_n(x) - f_K(x)\rvert \leqslant \lVert f_K\rVert_\infty + 1.$$ Since that holds for all $x\in N^c$, it follows that $\lVert f\rVert_\infty \leqslant \lVert f_K\rVert_\infty + 1 < \infty$.

Comment: OK it seems clear to me now. Had we not had uniform convergence then you wouldn't have been able to write "for all $x\in N^C$"?

Comment: Well, to conclude the essential boundedness, it would suffice to have a pointwise a.e. convergent sequence that is uniformly essentially bounded. But the norm of $L^\infty$ is that of uniform convergence on some conegligible set, so it's necessary to conclude the convergence of the sequence in $L^\infty$. For everything else, it's just a convenient thing to avoid looking at individual points.